# Why can't I initialize a variables in same moment I declare them in class

Tags: java, oop

I have code like in example:

```
public class Circle extends Shape{
private double radius=1;
private final double PI = Math.PI;
private Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);

public Circle(double radius){
    super("Circle");
    this.radius = radius;
}
public Circle(){
    super("Circle");
    String help;
    do{
        System.out.print("Write radius: ");
        help = get.nextLine();
    }while(Cnauka.isDouble(help) == false);
    this.radius = Double.parseDouble(help);
}
@Override
public double area(){
    return radius * radius * PI;
}}
```

And i have question about that variable radius. Why can i initialize them with value 1? Isn't it not property?

Comment: You can iniatlize it, but if you are goint to give it a new value when you call the constructor...better not do it.

Comment: Why not? It's not final, so you can write to it as many times as you want. Of course, it's better to do it either there or in the constructor.

Comment: You can always do inline initialization in a class, though it is better to do it in constructor when there is logic/error handling etc.
Refer this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because, a class for itself has no memory, some memory is allocated to it when its object is created, and thus you cant initialize class objects while declaring.. This applies to all object oriented languages like c++ as well and not only java..(excluding const staticvariables in c++)

Comment: It explain me everything :)